# Placing Fixed Modal Headers and Footers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using the **Bootstrap Modal** to display some content on my webpage. I have set the height of the modal to a fixed 80% to work properly in long screens because I have a lot of content in the modal-body. With the 80% height I would like the Header and the Footer to be fixed in their places but the entire content seems to be scrollable i.e. either my header or footer go on scrolling. I want to keep the header and footer fixed on their places with the modal-body being scrollable. I have tried using position:absolute and position:fixed but it does not seem to be working. How can this be done i.e. keep the header and footer fixed with the body scrollable ?

Comment: please add a fiddle or share some code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the height of the .modal-body in and give it overflow-y: auto. Also reset .modal-dialog overflow value to initial.

```
    .modal{
    display: block !important; /* I added this to see the modal, you don't need this */
}

/* Important part */
.modal-dialog{
    overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body{
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this below css will may help you.

```
.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
    max-height: 600px !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
```

}